# Odd one out of images

Tags: odd-one-out

Spot the odd one out.

You must justify your answer.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [A for Gardner, C for Highlanders, A for Peron, ?, I for the engine, R for Daley](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney_Alphabet). So the odd one out is probably the fourth (though I can't identify it). **Update:** [Mohirl](/users/29972/mohirl) (thanks!) tells me the fourth is Gareth Hunt. He's used for Cockney rhyming slang rather than Cockney alphabet so is, in fact, the odd one out.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the expected answer, but it's still technically correct.

The odd one out is the

> top middle one

because

> it's the only one with two people rather than one.

Comment: Not only that: it's also the only one that shows someone's both hands. +1.

Comment: @msh210 -- Good point!